# Android application Toast.makeText -error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have problem due to the fact that my Android Studio 
flags between  word

context and this -; expected
text and "Messages" ; expected
before .show ; expected and unexpected token I suppose .show

That does not make sense as the code is working perfectly in the tutorial but it is made in 2018 I wonder what could be issue or what more important what is the solutions?
Thanks you for all the answers :)

```
private void UserMenuSelector(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            Context context;
            Object text;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                Toast.makeText(context this, text "Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(context this, text "Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_friends:
                Toast.makeText(context this, text "Friend List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_find_friends:
                Toast.makeText(context this, text "Find Friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_messages:
                Toast.makeText(context this, text "Messages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Toast.makeText(context this, text "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_Logout:
                Toast.makeText(context this, text "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void show() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Typos. You seem to be transcribing code from an image or video of an IDE that has parameter name hints enabled. You don't include those in your code. For example, `Toast.makeText(this, "Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show();`.

Comment: @MikeM. Typo in your comment, you forgot the closing bracket `)` in toast

Comment: @NileshRathod Yeah, good catch. I just copied/pasted their first one. Didn't notice. Too late to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Toast.makeText()` required three parameters

- **`Context`**: The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.
- **`text`**: The text to show. Can be formatted text.
- **`duration`**: How long to display the message. Either `LENGTH_SHORT` or `LENGTH_LONG` Value is `LENGTH_SHORT`, or `LENGTH_LONG`

Use this

```
 Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 // or this
 Toast.makeText(this, "Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Instead of this

```
 Toast.makeText(context this,text "Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Toast.makeText(context this, text "Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show();
```

Remove context and text from the arguments of the toast.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Do this for all the toasts.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void UserMenuSelector(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            Context context;
            Object text;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                Toast.makeText(this, text "Profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(this, text "Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_friends:
                Toast.makeText(this, text "Friend List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_find_friends:
                Toast.makeText(this, text "Find Friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_messages:
                Toast.makeText(this, text "Messages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, text "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_Logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, text "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you are passing string argument as `text "Logout"` which is wrong.

The argument passed to the `makeText()` is wrong. You shoud call the method as

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```